# Django Display Data into HTML Table with finite rows

Tags: html, django

I have a have a form where someone can sign up for a number of slots for a monthly event. I would like to display this data in an html table so other users know how many slots remain for that event. How do I get the data into the table and have it fill the next set of slots if those above it are already filled?

Here is my view to pull how many slots (pipette_number) someone requested:

```
def AM_reservation(request, year, month, change=None):
     year, month = int(year), int(month)

     AM_pipettes = Entry.objects.filter(pipette_number, Time=Morning, date__year=year, date__month=month)
     AM = Time(Morning)
     AM_slots = [0,17]

    for AM_pipettes in AM_slots:
        entries = current = False
        if AM_pipettes:
            entries = Entry.objects.filter(pipette_number, Time=Morning, date__year=year, date__month=month)
            if year == nyear and month == nmonth:
                current = True
```

Note there are 18 slots per event. Do I need to put these into a list and label each slot with a number?

Here is my for loops in the html:

```
{% for AM_pipettes in AM_slot %}
    <tr>

            <td class= {% if AM_pipettes == 0 %}"empty"{% endif %}
            {% if AM_pipettes != 0 and not current %}"AM_slot"
            {% endif %} >

            {% if AM_slot != 0 %}
                {{ AM_slot }}
                {% for entry in entries %}
                    <br />
                    <b>{{ entry.creator }}</b>: {{ entry.short|safe }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

---Update---
Model.py code for Time choice:

```
Time_Choices = (
        (Morning, 'AM'), (Afternoon, 'PM'))
 Time = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                  choices= Time_Choices,
                                  default=Morning)
```

Comment: It seems to me that there are several errors in your code, and because of this it's not so clear what you are trying to do. For example, in your view `AM_slots = [0,17]` creates a list of only 2 elements (the number "0" and the number "17"), you should change it and use [range()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) instead. And I don't know why you use `AM_pipettes`, that is a Queryset you got from the `Entry.objects.filter`, as the variable in `for AM_pipettes in AM_slots:`.
(check also the filter options in `Entry.objects.filter`). And what are `Time` and `Morning`?

Comment: Your view should return an HTTP response, maybe something like ``return render(request, 'amslot.html', {'AM_slot': AM_slots, 'entries': entries}``, besides the errors help_asap has pointed to. Correct please also the indentation. In your template you also have forgotten to close the table cell - no ``</td>``.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments! In my model I have a choice to pick a Time_Choice. I've added the model code to the above section. That is where I'm getting Time and Morning. How should I filter by this parameter?

Comment: Ok, first thing first: in your model `Morning` and `Afternoon` must be strings (otherwise they will be considered undefined variables and throw a NameError). Something like `Time_Choices = (('Morning', 'AM'), ('Afternoon', 'PM'))` and change also `default='Morning'`. Have a deeper look to the [examples in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#choices) (extra tip: use lowercase names for class fields, so `time` not `Time`).

Comment: As for filtering by the `time` field, `Entry.objects.filter(time='Morning', date__year=year, date__month=month)` should do the trick. Notice that `time` MUST be the name of the models's field (I assume that you put it lowercase as I suggested you :P) and notice also that `Morning` is a string. Check very well the doc for the [Field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#id4). All in all, check your code using `python manage.py check` (or `python manage.py validate` if you use Django<1.6) and reach a working state (i.e.`python manage runserver` runs without errors)